# Attempting to write read and write files with java, results in blank output files

Tags: java

I have a file 'A.txt' which consists of 60 lines. Each line contains a single number from 1 to 60.  I also have a folder DD that contains 2 files, labelled 'DD1.txt' and 'DD2.txt'
File DD1 has 3 lines. Each line of DD1 has 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 . Similarly file DD2 also has 3 lines. Each line of DD2 has 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.

What I am trying to do is first read the first line of the A.txt, which calculates with all the lines of DD1 and writes the calculated value, and calculates with all the lines of DD2 and writes the output value. Thus I have 60 X 2 = 120 files to be created. Each file should have 2 lines. But I am getting only 2 files which is inside blank at the moment.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Sample {
    private static final String FILEA = "E:\\SP\\A.txt";
    private static String FILEH = "E:\\SP\\DD\\DD";

    private static String FILER = "E:\\SP\\Result\\Result";
    private static final String FILEEXE = ".txt";
    private static BufferedReader br = null, br1 = null, br2 = null;

    private static BufferedWriter bw = null;
    private static FileWriter fw = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        final double C1 = -3.75, C2 = 1.14;
        double T = 0, R = 0, E = 0, Efficiency = 1;

        System.out.println("Enter the value of Efficiency:");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Efficiency = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

        try {
            String sCurrentLine, sCurrentLine1, sCurrentLine2;
            int i = 0;
            br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILEA));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br1.readLine()) != null)
            {
                i++;
                String FILEH1 = FILEH + i + FILEEXE;
                String FILER1 = FILER + i + FILEEXE;
                br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILEH1));
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILER1));
                int count = 0;
                while ((sCurrentLine1 = br2.readLine()) != null)
                {

                    T = Double.parseDouble(sCurrentLine1);
                    R = Double.parseDouble(sCurrentLine);

                    E = R * 24 * (T * 0.024);
                    bw.write(Double.toString(E));
                    bw.newLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }//end trycatch
    }
}
```

Comment: try closing the `bw` object after the inner `while` has completed

Comment: Also, do not silent swallow exceptions,  there may be a big hint there

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes I did trying closing bw  but when I did it creates I file and stops

Comment: what does the exception say?

Comment: @ScaryWombat oh no. it is asking for DD3.txt I have only DD1 and DD2.

(The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Sample.main(Sample.java:39)

Comment: good, you know what to fix then

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes but I am now confused about how to fix :(

Comment: @Shyam When while loop is iterating over lines from FileA you are opening a new file because of increment of variable 'i'

Comment: @Nick Div, now I am trying to check the number of files inside 'DD' folder then run the loop. Seriously doing java for the first time :)

Comment: @Shyam And is it working as expected?
Keep the following outside while loop and change it after first file has finished reading
i++;

String FILEH1 = FILEH + i + FILEEXE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you made your calculation inside the while loop try bw.write("\r\n"); Then after the while loop try closing the write as bw.close(); Hope this works for you.

```
   bw.write(Double.toString(E));
   bw.write("\r\n");
}
bw.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I have fixed this problem by doing some changes with my loop and yes when I did bw.close() after each write.